# PHP session lost even for simple test page

Tags: php, apache, session, config

**Code**

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['test'] = 5;
```

**Output**

```
array(0) { }
```

**phpinfo()**

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user mm
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly On  On
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  16  16
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   1   1
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php5   /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

also `/tmp` is writeable:

```
# ls -la /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 22 root    root        4096 Aug 26 09:44 .
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `var_dump` after `$_SESSION` set. I guess you dump early

Comment: @Bora he can get the `var_dump` on second refresh

Comment: @Mr.Alien: `SESSION` is not like `COOKIE` it can be printed once it set

Comment: @Mr.Alien You may be right.

Comment: @Akam see the `var_dump()` order

Comment: @Bora var_dump after set will always be filled and will not tell you if session is working. This example should show a result on second refresh.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I knew as mentioned it should be printed after it set and this is usual.

Comment: What's the return value of `session_start()`? Also, remember to add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your session doesn't seem to start, you can do two things:

1. Check the return value of `session_start()`; it will return `false` if there was an error.
2. Reveal the notices and warnings:

   ```
   error_reporting(-1); 
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   ```

   On a live server you may wish to use [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) instead.
3. Check whether the session is properly perpetuated, either via cookies or by passing the session id via the query string (not recommended).

Comment: This is the general way to solve this. Also see [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18439359/956397). @Jack: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for test of your example you must run this file at 2 time! one for fill session variable and next time for printing sessions array. so check out below example:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 5;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Like I wrote in the [comments above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439090/php-session-lost-even-for-simple-test-page#comment27092876_18439090) this will not tell you if session is working. It will always show `"test" => 5`. Also the problem is already [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18439359/956397). Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`session.save_path` is `/var/lib/php5` not `/tmp`!

After

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php5
$ sudo rm /var/lib/php5/*
```

Session starts working again.

[Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) is right: Don't use 777 for session files!

```
$ sudo chown wwwrun:www /var/lib/php5
$ sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/php5
```

Comment: It's not recommended to give `777` permissions. Just `chown` the folder with the correct user and have `700` as the permissions.